# Arch linux: How to exclude files from subfolder while using rsync for copying

Tags: linux, bash, file-transfer, rsync

I wanted to make a copy of files from one directory (folder "test2") to another directory (folder "Destination") while using rsync in linux console. The only problem? I want to copy all the .png and .jpg files from main folder ("test2") while excluding/skipping all the subfolders (in this example subfolder "abcd") that contain .png or .jpg files as well as .jpg or .png files from subfolders.

I made a bash script which I run but was not successful, since it copied all the files from my source folder to my destination folder.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#Define pathways to source and destination folder

source_folder="/home/Minja/Desktop/Test2/"
destination_folder="/home/Minja/Desktop/Destination/"

#Name of excluded subfolder
excluded_directory="abcd"

#Use of rsync with defined options
rsync -av --include="*/" --include="*.jpg" --include="*.png" \
   --exclude="*" "$source_folder" "$destination_folder"

#Manually exclude/include files from excluded directory
rsync -av --exclude="*" --include="*.jpg" --include="*.png" \
   "$source_folder/$excluded_directory/" "$destination_folder/$excluded_directory/"
```

Do you have any recommendation how to resolve this issue?
How to include .jpg and .png files from subfolders as well?

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself. First you say "_I want to copy all the .png and .jpg files from main folder […] while excluding/skipping all the subfolders […] that contain .png or .jpg files as well as .jpg or .png files from subfolders._", which I read as meaning you don't want any subdirectories at all. But then you say exactly the opposite by asking "_How to include .jpg and .png files from subfolders as well?_" Which is it?

Comment: Adding examples to your question of what to include and exclude would be helpful.

Comment: I'm now wondering if the "_as well as .jpg or .png files from subfolders_" was intended to mean that you wanted to include these rather than exclude them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to avoid copying anything from subdirectories, and just copy the PNG and JPG files from the top level. However, your last sentence appears to contradict this requirement.

Assuming the first part of your question is correct, disable the recursive copy (`-r`, implied by `-a`):

```
rsync --dry-run -av --no-r "$source_folder"/*.png "$source_folder"/*.jpg "$destination_folder"
```

If you have too many files for the shell to enumerate using `*.png` and `*.jpg`, re-enable the recursive copy but exclude all subdirectories:

```
rsync --dry-run -av --exclude '*/' --include '*.png' --include '*.jpg' --exclude '*' "$source_folder/" "$destination_folder"
```

In both cases, remove `--dry-run` when you have seen that `rsync` will do what you want it to do, and it will go ahead and really perform the copy.